# ffmpeg - Generate a ping-pong looping Gif with images as input

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm wondering if this is actually possible.

I have a directory of images, which I use as input to ffmpeg to output a GIF file.

That works fine, but what I want to do is to modify it so it loops back on itself back to the starting image.

Is this possible?

Comment: [Check out the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#gif-2)

Comment: Yeah I've been there, that doesn't answer my question

Comment: oh i got it now... sorry. I think you need to either copy these input images or use `-f concat` and list all the image files forward then backwards.